# Rails - Capybara won't process ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, erb

Here is my partial code:

```
<% @birds.each do |bird| %>
  <p>
  <%= "#{bird.name} , #{bird.genus} #{bird.species}"%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And here is my RSpec code that tests the webpage:

```
let(:bird) { FactoryGirl.create(:bird) }
before { visit birds_path }
it { should have_text("#{bird.name}") }
```

This test fails:

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_text("#{bird.name}") }
   expected #has_text?("Bird_1") to return true, got false
```

Does anyone know why that happens and how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You can debug what went wrong using `save_and_open_page` - https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105#file-capybara-cheat-sheet-L55

Comment: it says `undefined local variable or method 'save_and_open_page'`

Answer (score 0):

The let is called the first time you try to access bird. Since you already visited the page via the before block, the bird was not yet created.

Please try the following:

```
it "should have bird" do
  bird = FactoryGirl.create(:bird)
  visit bird_path
  expect(page).to have_content(bird.name)
end
```

Comment: LOL. We had an 8 second difference between our posts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently was that FactoryGirl wasn't finished creating the object, so the object didn't show up on the page. Instead of

```
let(:bird) { FactoryGirl.create(:bird) }
```

it should have been

```
let!(:bird) { FactoryGirl.create(:bird) }
```

Thanks for the suggestions though.